# Respond CMS install angular error

Tags: angularjs, content-management-system, respondcms

So I have managed to install Respond CMS v4 on my hosting server, or so I think.
When I go to http://app.bedreweb.com nothing shows up.
Viewing the debugger in Chrome, reveals it is failing with angular

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=respond&p1=Error%3…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)
```

I have run composer, and have my db and everything else in place.
Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, by replacing all the respond files with that of the v4 branch on github, instead of using the Master branch.